# Grow Logical Volume - Missing Partition

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 VM, setup with LVM, but the partition is missing. I started by running a pvcreate, vgcreate, and then lvcreate.

An lsblk shows the following:

```
sdb                   8:16   0   200G  0 disk 
└─data-data         253:0    0   150G  0 lvm
```

There is data in /dev/data/data - and I am trying to increase it by 50GB. Using gparted shows the following when I print the info:

```
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)                                         
Disk /dev/sdb: 215GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 
(parted)
```

PVS Output:

```
PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree 
  /dev/sda3  vgubuntu lvm2 a--    99.49g 32.00m
  /dev/sdb   data     lvm2 a--  <150.00g     0
```

VGS Output:

```
VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree 
  data       1   1   0 wz--n- <150.00g     0 
  vgubuntu   1   2   0 wz--n-   99.49g 32.00m
```

LVS Output:

```
LV     VG       Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  data   data     -wi-a----- <150.00g                                                    
  root   vgubuntu -wi-ao----   97.55g                                                    
  swap_1 vgubuntu -wi-ao----   <1.91g
```

I am completely stumped how to grow /dev/data/data without losing any data. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like you added a new device which became sdb and then created an LVM device on it without partitioning first. There will be no partitions unless you create them. What you have done is very non standard. You may find that you can create a 50G partition in currently unallocated space on sdb. Then it should be simple to add that to the data volume group Alternatively backup your data, start again, then restore your data